# InnoDB Tablespace critical error in great need of a fix

Tags: mysql, innodb

Link to screenshot : http://www.nouvellesduquartier.com/i/1/p/Munin_%20Critical_MySql_InnoDB_.JPG

Question: Could the error shown on the screenshot be the reason why my site is very slow?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA SE site. Take note: this is **NOT** a jobs board. If you come here offering payment, your question will be closed and ignored.

Comment: Oh sorry Marc, edited. What do you mean by DBA SE site? could you point me to one please?

Answer (score 0):

Your free space in the current innodb file (ibdata[1] ?) is decreasing.
It doesn't necessarily mean that your website is slow.

Maybe the number of users (concurrent users) has increased in the last few days ? (also causing lots of inserts int he DB?)

There is no error in the print screen. it's just your monitoring system, reporting a value that have reached the critical threshold.